# IBM MFP 8 PushNotification adapter

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Need to create an adapter using IBM MFP 8 as PUSH ADAPTER to send the notification from App to the user. 
Ex: if i confirm/success any steps, send a notification to user that this step completed successfully.

How to do the same ?

Comment: This link might help you to create your adapter 
https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/

Answer (score 0):

The push service exposes a REST endpoint for dispatching notifications. 
The Java adapter also exposes REST endpoints.

It is unclear why you wish to complicate matters by wrapping the Push service endpoints within an adapter and then let a client access the Java endpoint, which in turn calls the Push endpoint.

Whether you access Java adapter from non-MFP clients or Push service, you still have to go with OAuth token obtained from confidential clients. And Java adapter scopes and Push adapter scopes are very different.

If you really need to do what you are asking, you could do two things:

a) first obtain a token covering all the scopes your Java adapter + Push service needs and then pass this along when calling Java adapter. Within Java adapter, use AuthenticationContext to retrieve the token data and use this to invoke the Push service.

b) obtain a token covering only Java adapter. Once the call is within Java adapter, invoke the token endpoint to obtain a token covering all the scopes Push service needs. Now invoke the Push service separately, with the Push token and dispatch the notification.